# How to add user avatar in navbar after sign in?

Tags: css, navbar, avatar

I made a navbar using bootstrap 4.
[image]

Now I want to add user avatar and name after sign in mentioned as circle.  I have no idea how to do this. If you give or scratch it help me lot.

Now, my idea is when user sign in replace the navbar with a new navbar that have a place with avatar. Or replace the `Sign in` text with the avatar that is more complex to me. Second is need more css code I guess.

I load the navbar using following rule.  Then there is a possibility to `nav-placeholder` when `sign in` button will be clicked.

```
 <body>
    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="nav-placeholder">
    </div>
    <div id="carousel">
    </div>

<div id="successfulModal">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("newnavbar.html");
  $("#carousel").load("carousel.php");
});
</script>
```

My navbar code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Matir Dokan</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
    .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */ 
    .jumbotron {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
    footer {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 25px;
    }
    .modal-backdrop
    {
        background: none;
    }
</style>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Matir Dokan</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle toggle1" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Object Type
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu menu1" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="add_form(name)" id="menu1_item" name="toy">Toy</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider" ></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="add_form(name)" id="menu1_item" name="Furniture">Furniture</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="add_form(name)" id="menu1_item" name="Gift">Gift</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="add_form(name)" id="menu1_item" name="Household">Household</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="add_form(name)" id="menu1_item" name="Instrument">Instrument</a>
                </div>
            </li>


            <script>

                $(function(){

                    $(".menu1 a").click(function(){

                        $(".toggle1").text($(this).text());

                    });

                });
            </script>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle toggle2" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Material Type
                </a>


                <div class="dropdown-menu menu2" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Mud</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cloth</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Thread</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Jute</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cotton</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cane</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Bamboo</a>
                </div>
            </li>


            <script>

                $(function(){

                    $(".menu2 a").click(function(){

                        $(".toggle2").text($(this).text());

                    });

                });
            </script>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="object" value="">
                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="material">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function add_form(name){
                    document.getElementById("object").value=name;

                    console.log(document.getElementById("object").value);
                }
            </script>



            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Auction</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle toggle3" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Cart
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu menu3" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                        <div>
                            <img src="delete1.jpg" style="width: 40px;height: 40px"> Unionbay park  <span class="dropdown-product-details">2 x $24.89</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                        <div>
                            <img src="delete1.jpg" style="width: 40px;height: 40px"> Unionbay park
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                        <div>
                            <img src="delete1.jpg" style="width: 40px;height: 40px"> Unionbay park
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                        <a class="btn btn-sm  btn-secondary" href="cart.html">View Cart</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="checkout-address.html">Checkout</a>
                    </a>


                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Sign Up</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signIn" style="margin-left:10px">Sign In</button></li>

                    <!-- Modal content-->




                    <div class="modal fade" id="signUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <!--<label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email address:</label>-->
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="signUpEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <!--<label for="pwd" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>-->
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signUpPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" onchange="check_pass()">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <!--<label for="pwd" class="col-form-label">Confirm Password:</label>-->
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signUpConPassword" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onchange="check_pass()">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="signUpSubmit" disabled="true" >Sign Up</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_pass() 
    {
        //alert(document.getElementById('signUpPassword').value);
    if (document.getElementById('signUpPassword').value ==
            document.getElementById('signUpConPassword').value) {
        document.getElementById('signUpSubmit').disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('signUpSubmit').disabled = true;
    }
}
$('#signUpSubmit').click(function() 
{

    $('#signUp').modal('toggle');
    //alert("signup completed");
    var email=document.getElementById('signUpEmail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('signUpPassword').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'signup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: password
        },
        success: function() {
            //alert('Email Sent');
        }               
    });
});
</script>



                    <div class="modal fade" id="signIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign In</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <!--<label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email address:</label>-->
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <!--<label for="pwd" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>-->
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>

                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put php function in navbar.

```
<?php

if ( isset($_SESSION['session name here']) ) { ?>

   // here put navigation bar which you want to show after sig in.

<?php } else { ?>


  // here put navigation bar which  you want to show before sign in.

<?php } ?>
```

Now it sould work.

Comment: Do you say something like this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TVYnSWbpkb/ Ignor comment.

Comment: Your idea works in primary test. I try to implement this. Thank  you.

Comment: Yeah this is a method navigation dynamic. make one navbar, divide into two parts, one show when user not sing in and the other one show when the user is sign in.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can keep the avatr field hidden or display as none and on successful login you can unhide the avatar class
Something like this

> if(result == "validUser"){
>       // If the user is valid add the class
>           $("#avatarImg").addClass("showAvatar");
>        $("#avatarImg").addClass("rounded-circle");
>   }
>   .showAvatar{
> display:block;
> }

Comment: Suppose, I check the user is invalid but after some time when the user is valid is it change automatically by your solution? see my edited question. That may help you with better idea.